# Put a full citation into the main body of a document

Tags: beamer, bibtex, citing

I am making a presentation through `beamer`.

I need to put some full citations instead of simple ones into the main content of my document.

For example, instead of saying according to George (2015), I want to put the exact content of this bib entry here.

Is there a easy way to do it without writing all the contents by myself?

Comment: With traditional BibTeX, there is the `usebib` package, which provides the command `\usebibentry{ key }{ field }`; thus it would be trivial to create your own custom 'full cite' command. The `biblatex` package, on the other hand, includes the command `\fullcite`.

Answer (score 1):

My personal opinion is that bibliographies and references need to be radically different in presentation than in articles:

1. It is impossible for the audience to keep track of numeric references,
2. author-year style can work but you need to show the full entry on first appearance for the part of the audience not familiar with the relevant literature.
3. a full bibliography at the end of the talk is very useless unless you want to comment on the refs (or you are publishing the slides for offline consultation)
4. you want finer control on how the entries are displayed because they need to be minimal to improve readability

To me, because of these reasons, the solutions offered by bibliographic packages are both an overkill and inadequate.
An option is using `biblatex` and customise heavily the output, but I prefer a simpler, if ad-hoc, approach based on some very simple custom macros.

```
\newcommand{\bibliotitlestyle}[1]{\textbf{\large #1}\par}

\newif\ifinbiblio
\newcounter{bibkey}
\newenvironment{biblio}[2][long]{%
    \ifx!#2!\else%
        \bibliotitlestyle{#2}%
    \fi%
    \begin{thebibliography}{}%
    \inbibliotrue%
    \setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry title}[#1]%
}{%
    \inbibliofalse%
    \end{thebibliography}%
}

% \biblioref{author}{year}{title}{publication}
\newcommand{\biblioref}[5][short]{
    \setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry title}[#1]%
    \stepcounter{bibkey}%
    \ifinbiblio%
        \bibitem{\thebibkey}%
            #4
            \newblock #2, #3
            \ifx!#5!\else\newblock {\em #5}\fi%
    \else%
        \begin{biblio}{}
            \bibitem{\thebibkey}
                #4
                \newblock #2, #3
                \ifx!#5!\else\newblock {\em #5}\fi
        \end{biblio}
    \fi
}
```

These two macros typeset references with custom data using beamer's style (however that is defined by your theme).

If you want a single entry inlined in a slide use

```
\biblioref{author}{year}{title}{publication}
```

If you want a list

```
\begin{biblio}{References}
    \biblioref{author}{year}{title}{publication}
    \biblioref{author}{year}{title}{publication}
    % ...
\end{biblio}
```

The main disadvantage is of course that if you want to use an entry more than once you have to repeat the data. This can be easily fixed using custom macros for each reference: this way you have full control on what gets displayed and where, avoid duplication and it is still not too cumbersome because you typically do not have too many references in slides.